# SpringBoot application-dev.yml Jhipster error when starting the application

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

When I try to start the SpringBoot application, i get this error:

**APPLICATION FAILED TO START*********************************Description:****Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.type' to java.lang.Class<javax.sql.DataSource>:****    Property: spring.datasource.type**    Value: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"**    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml] - 33:11__    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Class<javax.sql.DataSource> (caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)____Action:__**Update your application's configuration**

My configuration:

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/licentapp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: proot
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
              cachePrepStmts: true
              prepStmtCacheSize: 250
              prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
              useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      database: MYSQL
      show-sql: true
      properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.BeanClassLoaderAwareJCacheRegionFactory
```

I cannot see what's wrong over here. Maybe there is a problem in pom.xml file?

I tried to update the depedency in pom.xml file, adding

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but no success.

Deleted the long useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC but stil got the same error.

Comment: It looks like MySQL is missing as a dependency.

Comment: Right.  The standard Java libraries do not include MySQL driver.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html for instructions